# Is there any continuation to the marriage ceremony that got cut in the middle of the last episode of Shippuden?

Tags: naruto

Episode 500 of *Shippuden*, the final episode shows some of the characters' marriage. However, their marriage ceremony fades through the white door.

I'd at least thought Naruto would be there for their ceremony and some happy moments before the story closes, but no.

Is there any official statement why it got cut/ended like that? Is there any OVA/continuation to their marriage ceremony somewhere?

(I know there's *Boruto*, but this question is more about their marriage ceremony, not the story long after that)

Comment: No, as I remember 500 is last but there is the some movie and part related to boruto and naruto gaiden

Comment: @mirroroftruth , This should be against some policy I think. :). Us consumer's mental health is seriously affected when there is this thunderbolt stop.